# How to add an inset_axes to a subplot with matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, subplot

I am trying to plot a number of subplots in matplotlib, each subplot should have an inset axes. I can get the code examples to work for a single axis with a inset axes added using `mpl_toolkits.axes_grid.inset_locator.inset_axes()`, and I can plot subplots fine without the inset axes, but when trying to do the same for subplots in a loop, I get `TypeError: 'AxesHostAxes' object is not callable` **on the second subplot**.  This seems a bit strange that it should work when `number_of_plots` is ==1, but not >1.  How should I be doing it, or is it a bug? (`matplotlib.__version__` is '1.5.1')

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid.inset_locator import inset_axes
import numpy as np
x = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 100)
y = np.sin(x)
n_row, n_col = 4, 4
fig = plt.figure(1,(10,10))
#number_of_plots = 1 Works!
number_of_plots = n_row * n_col # Does not work!
for idx in range(number_of_plots):
    ax = fig.add_subplot(n_row, n_col, idx + 1)
    ax.plot(x, y)
    inset_axes = inset_axes(ax,
                            width="30%", # width = 30% of parent_bbox
                            height="30%", # height : 1 inch
                            )
```

[image: Error in inset_axes]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For future readers: [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17458580/embedding-small-plots-inside-subplots-in-matplotlib) shows methods to create insets in matplotlib.

---

Concrete answer to the question here: It's not a bug. You are redefining `inset_axes`.

Before the line `inset_axes = inset_axes(...)`, `inset_axes` is a function from `mpl_toolkits.axes_grid.inset_locator`. After that, `inset_axes` is the return of that function, which is an `AxesHostAxes`.

The general advice is of course: **Never call a variable by the same name as a function you import or use in your code.**

The concrete solution:

```
ax_ins = inset_axes(ax, width="30%",  height="30%")
```