# specific location for inset axes

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph

I want to create a set of axes to form an inset at a specific location in the parent set of axes.  It is therefore not appropriate to just use the parameter `loc=1,2,3` in the `inset_axes` as shown here:

```
inset_axes = inset_axes(parent_axes,
                    width="30%", # width = 30% of parent_bbox
                    height=1., # height : 1 inch
                    loc=3)
```

However, I would like something close to this.  And the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14589600/matplotlib-insets-in-subplots) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19335900/inset-axes-anchored-to-specific-points-in-data-coordinates) seem to be answers to questions slightly more complicated than mine.

So, the question is is there a parameter that I can replace in the above code that will allow custom locations of the inset axes within the parent axes?  I've tried to use the `bbox_to_anchor` but do not understand it's specification or behavior from the [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/axes_grid/api/inset_locator_api.html).  Specifically I've tried:

```
 inset_axes = inset_axes(parent_axes,
                        width="30%", # width = 30% of parent_bbox
                        height=1., # height : 1 inch
                        bbox_to_anchor=(0.4,0.1))
```

to try to get the anchor for the left and bottom of the inset to be at 40% and 10% of the x and y axis respectively.  Or, I tried to put it in absolute coordinates:

```
inset_axes = inset_axes(parent_axes,
                            width="30%", # width = 30% of parent_bbox
                            height=1., # height : 1 inch
                            bbox_to_anchor=(-4,-100))
```

Neither of these worked correctly and gave me a warning that I couldn't interpret.

More generally, it seems like `loc` is a pretty standard parameter in many functions belonging to `matplotlib`, so, is there a general solution to this problem that can be used anywhere?  It seems like that's what `bbox_to_anchor` is but again, I can't figure out how to use it correctly.

Comment: You should not be assigning the `inset_axes` function to a similarly named variable. Use something like  `inset = inset_axes(...)`.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The approach you took is in principle correct. However, just like [when placing a legend](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43439132/4124317) with `bbox_to_anchor`, the location is determined as an interplay between `bbox_to_anchor` and `loc`. Most of the explanation in the above linked answer applies here as well.

The default `loc` for [`inset_axes`](https://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/axes_grid/api/inset_locator_api.html#mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1.inset_locator.inset_axes) is `loc=1` ("upper right"). This means that if you you specify `bbox_to_anchor=(0.4,0.1)`, those will be the coordinates of the upper right corner, not the lower left one.
You would therefore need to specify `loc=3` to have the lower left corner of the inset positionned at `(0.4,0.1)`.

However, specifying a bounding as a 2-tuple only makes sense if not specifying the width and height in relative units (`"30%"`). Or in other words, in order to use relative units you need to use a 4-tuple notation for the `bbox_to_anchor`.

In case of specifying the `bbox_to_anchor` in axes units one needs to use the `bbox_transform` argument, again, just as with legends explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43439132/4124317), and set it to `ax.transAxes`.

```
plt.figure(figsize=(6,3))
ax = plt.subplot(221)
ax.set_title("100%, (0.5,1-0.3,.3,.3)")
ax.plot(xdata, ydata)
axins = inset_axes(ax, width="100%", height="100%", loc='upper left',
                   bbox_to_anchor=(0.5,1-0.3,.3,.3), bbox_transform=ax.transAxes)


ax = plt.subplot(222)
ax.set_title("30%, (0.5,0,1,1)")
ax.plot(xdata, ydata)
axins = inset_axes(ax, width="30%", height="30%", loc='upper left',
                   bbox_to_anchor=(0.5,0,1,1), bbox_transform=ax.transAxes)
```

[image]

Find a complete example on the matplotlib page: [Inset Locator Demo](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/axes_grid1/inset_locator_demo.html)

**Another option** is to use `InsetPosition` instead of `inset_axes` and to give an existing axes a new position. `InsetPosition` takes the x and y coordinates of the lower left corner of the axes in normalized axes coordinates, as well as the width and height as input.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1.inset_locator import InsetPosition

fig, ax= plt.subplots()

iax = plt.axes([0, 0, 1, 1])
ip = InsetPosition(ax, [0.4, 0.1, 0.3, 0.7]) #posx, posy, width, height
iax.set_axes_locator(ip)

iax.plot([1,2,4])
plt.show()
```

**Finally** one should mention that from matplotlib 3.0 on, you can use [`matplotlib.axes.Axes.inset_axes`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.inset_axes.html)

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.figure(figsize=(6,3))
ax = plt.subplot(221)
ax.set_title("ax.inset_axes, (0.5,1-0.3,.3,.3)")
ax.plot([0,4], [0,10])
axins = ax.inset_axes((0.5,1-0.3,.3,.3))

plt.show()
```

The result is roughly the same, except that `mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1.inset_locator.inset_axes` allows for a padding around the axes (and applies it by default), while `Axes.inset_axes` does not have this kind of padding.

[image]

Comment: I've tried `inset_axes(ax3, height="30%", width="70%", bbox_to_anchor=(0.4,0.6), loc=3)` but it produced a warning: `UserWarning: Unable to find pixel distance along axis for interval padding of ticks; assuming no interval padding needed.` and the inset appears as a tiny axis well outside the parent axes

Comment: You are right. There is either a bug in matplotlib or an error in the documentation. I'm trying to find out what's going on.

Comment: Does this mean I can stop constructing a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?  Or, can you share the one that you've apparently constructed?

Comment: Yep, I can easily reproduce the issue. You will find a mcve in [the issue that I have just opened](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/8952) on GitHub about this. I have also updated the answer for a workaround. This is probably as easy to use as inset axes.

Comment: Thanks, just read that post, when you say "Note that when explicitely supplying the `bbox_to_anchor` we at least...." did you mean `bbox_transform` ?

Comment: Is this workaround working for you or do you explicitely need one of width and height to be in percent and the other in inches?

Comment: I am used to getting an axis object in order to plot things, so I am confused by the example when I try to "reset" the axis the original plots are deformed.  I don't have time to produce a minimal, complete, and verifiable example for this so quickly: I have three plots (axis objects ax1,2,3) on a 3x1 grid.  Only the last one has an inset.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "reset"?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150440/discussion-between-villaa-and-importanceofbeingernest).

Comment: I updated the answer to show an actual solution to the problem.

Comment: I apparently used the `InsetPosition` workaround before.  I now want to use the `inset_axes` method because it is conceptually clearer to me.  I found it essential to read [the pull request conversation](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/8952) in order to understand what you did here.  I still can't figure out how the coordinates `(0.5,1-0.3,.3,.3)` and `(0.5,0,1,1)` produce the same location.  I thought the first two numbers represent the left and bottom of the inset axis, but I don't understand how `width` and `height` modify their meaning.

Comment: The `bbox_to_anchor` produces a box. Inside of this box an inset of the specified width and height is created and is aligned according to the `loc` parameter. The PR is still not merged. A preview version of the docs is [here](https://160-100939689-gh.circle-artifacts.com/0/home/circleci/project/doc/build/html/api/_as_gen/mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1.inset_locator.inset_axes.html). Together with this comes [an example](https://160-100939689-gh.circle-artifacts.com/0/home/circleci/project/doc/build/html/gallery/axes_grid1/inset_locator_demo.html), which might be more helpful.

Comment: Ok, I edited the question with my understanding of this documentation and what worked for me.  Feel free to edit/comment if something is misunderstood there.

Comment: What you call "Edit" and everything below rather seems like an answer than a question. Would you mind cutting it from the question and providing it as answer? This makes it much more useful for future readers.

Comment: Also since I wrote that new documentation, if you want to give some feedback on what was not so understandable it could help me improving the docs even further.

Comment: I moved that portion of the question to a new answer.  The hardest part I had with the documentation was the overall picture of things: i.e. figuring how why your different parameters sets gave identical results.  A major advance I made was realizing that the `width` and `height` parameters had in a sense nothing to do with the interpretation of the bounding box parameters.  Since the last two coordinates you gave for the 100% case was 0.3, and in the 30% case was 1 I thought somehow the size was the multiplication of those.  Suggest a place I can write more and I'll try to be clearer.

Comment: A good place for feedback is of course the [pull request itself](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/11060).

Answer (score 2):

Using the answer from ImportanceOfBeingErnest and several of the suggested links from the unreleased `matplotlib` documentation like [the locator demo](https://160-100939689-gh.circle-artifacts.com/0/home/circleci/project/doc/build/html/gallery/axes_grid1/inset_locator_demo.html) and the [`inset_axes` docs](https://160-100939689-gh.circle-artifacts.com/0/home/circleci/project/doc/build/html/api/_as_gen/mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1.inset_locator.inset_axes.html), it *still* took me some time to figure out how all the parameters behaved.  So, I will repeat my understanding here for clarity. I ended up using:

```
bbox_ll_x = 0.2
bbox_ll_y = 0
bbox_w = 1
bbox_h = 1
eps = 0.01
inset_axes = inset_axes(parent_axes, 
               height="30%", #height of inset axes as frac of bounding box
               width="70%",  #width of inset axes as frac of bounding box
               bbox_to_anchor=(bbox_ll_x,bbox_ll_y,bbox_w-bbox_ll_x,bbox_h), 
               loc='upper left',
               bbox_transform=parent_axes.transAxes)

parent_axes.add_patch(plt.Rectangle((bbox_ll_x, bbox_ll_y+eps),
               bbox_w-eps-bbox_ll_x, 
               bbox_h-eps, 
               ls="--", 
               ec="c", 
               fc="None",
               transform=parent_axes.transAxes))
```

`bbox_ll_x` is the x location of the lower left corner of the bounding box in the parent axis coordinates (that is the meaning of the `bbox_transform` input)

`bbox_ll_y` is the y location of the lower left corner of the bounding box in the parent axis coordinates

`bbox_w` is the width of the bounding box in parent axis coordinates

`bbox_h` is the height of the bounding box in parent axis coordinates

`eps` is a small number to get the rectangles to show up from under axes when drawing the rectangular bounding box.

I used the `add_patch` call in order to put a cyan dashed line that represents the inner edge of the bounding box that is drawn.

The trickiest part for me was realizing that the `height` and `width` inputs (when specified as percents) are relative to the bounding box size.  That's why (as noted in the links and the answer below) you *must* specify a 4-tuple for the `bbox_to_anchor` parameter if you specify the size of the inset axes in percents.  If you specify the size of the inset axes as percents and *don't* supply `bbox_w` or `bbox_h` how can `matplotlib` get the absolute size of the inset?

Another thing was that the `loc` parameter specifies where to anchor the inset axes within the bounding box.  As far as I can tell that's the only function of that parameter.

Comment: Thank you for taking time to organise what you have found in this answer! It as very helpfull for me

Comment: @gota no problem, I'm happy it was time well spent

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at the [`outset` library](https://github.com/mmore500/outset), which helps manage axes inset placement at different levels of abstraction --- including simple direct specification of inset size and placement.

### Axes-relative Layout

[image: axes-relative placement example]

outset provides the `OutsetGrid` class to manage a main axes (`OutsetGrid.source_axes`) and auxiliary axes (`OutsetGrid.outset_axes` array).

Auxiliary axes can be inset over the main axes using the `outset.inset_outsets` function.

```py
import outset as otst

# create main/auxiliary axes manager object 
grid = otst.OutsetGrid(1)  # one inset axes

grid.source_axes.axline((0, 0), (1, 1))  # plot y = x
grid.source_axes.set_xlim(0, 1) # set nice unit ax limits
grid.source_axes.set_ylim(0, 1)

otst.inset_outsets(  # position auxiliary axes over main axes
    grid, 
    insets=[(0.0, 0.6, 0.3, 0.3)],  # exact axes-relative coordinates
)

for spine in grid.outset_axes[0].spines.values():  # style inset axes
    spine.set_color("red")
    spine.set_linewidth(3)
```

### Mix Manual and Automatic Layout

[image: manual/automatic layout example]

Manual inset placement can be combined with automatic grid-based layout tools, as shown in this example.

```py
import outset as otst

# create main/auxiliary axes manager object 
grid = otst.OutsetGrid(4)  # 4 inset axes

grid.source_axes.axline((0, 0), (1, 1))  # plot y = x
grid.source_axes.set_xlim(0, 1) # set nice unit ax limits
grid.source_axes.set_ylim(0, 1)

otst.inset_outsets(  # position auxiliary axes over main axes
    grid,
    insets=[
        (0, 0.6, 0.3, 0.3),  # manual position, (x0, y0, width, height)
        *otst.util.layout_corner_insets(  # automatically positioned
            3, "SE",  # 3 axes in lower right corner
            inset_margin_size=(0, 0.1), # customize inset grid geometry
            inset_pad_ratio=0.3, 
            inset_grid_size=0.7,
       ),
    ],
)

# finishing touches styling inset axes
for ax in grid.outset_axes:
    for spine in ax.spines.values():
        spine.set_color("red")
        spine.set_linewidth(3)
```

### Absolute Layout (e.g., inches)

[image: absolute placement]

The original question asks how to create an inset axes that is 1 inch tall and 30% of axes width.
Here's how to convert absolute units (inches) to axes-relative units to get the one inch height.

```
import outset as otst

# create main/auxiliary axes manager object 
grid = otst.OutsetGrid(1)  # one inset

grid.source_axes.axline((0, 0), (1, 1))  # plot y = 1 - x
grid.source_axes.set_xlim(0, 1) # set nice unit ax limits
grid.source_axes.set_ylim(0, 1)

# calc main axes dimensions in inches...
bb = grid.source_axes.get_window_extent().transformed(
    grid.figure.dpi_scale_trans.inverted(),
)
# ... then calculate axes-relative height of one inch
inches_height = 1
relative_height = 1 / bb.height

otst.inset_outsets(  # position auxiliary axes over main axes
    grid,
    insets=[(0.4, 0.1, 0.3, relative_height)],  # (x0, y0, width, height)
    strip_ticks=False,  # keep axes ticks
    equalize_aspect=False,  # allow different aspects, main vs. insets
)
```

### Installation

`python3 -m pip install outset`

### Additional Features

The `OutsetGrid` class is derived from seaborn's `FacetGrid` class, which provides mechanisms to customize figure size and aspect ratio, among other things.
In addition to inset layout control, the library also provides convenient mechanisms to broadcast content over main/auxiliary axes (e.g., for zoom plots of the same content) and a seaborn-like data-oriented API to infer zoom inserts containing categorical subsets of a dataframe.

Refer to the outset [*quickstart guide*](https://mmore500.com/outset/quickstart.html) and [*gallery*](https://mmore500.com/outset/gallery.html) for more info.

***Disclosure**: am library author*