# How to update positions of inset axes in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

`set_position()` seems not to work for inset axes in matploltib, see code below:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1, figsize=(7.2, 7.2))
# make inset axes
axin = ax.inset_axes([0.1, 0.1, 0.2, 0.2])
# update position, NOT working
axin.set_position([0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2])
```

[image]

**Is there any way to update position of inset axes ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a [great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45378918/specific-location-for-inset-axes). I saw this and modified your code. I don't have enough knowledge to explain this so please refer to his answer.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1.inset_locator import InsetPosition

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1, figsize=(7.2, 7.2))
axin = ax.inset_axes([0.1, 0.1, 0.2, 0.2])

ip = InsetPosition(ax,[0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2])
axin.set_axes_locator(ip)
```

[image]

Comment: thanks, I guess this is the right way to update position of inset axes:)